# I'm having a positioning problem in instagram story clone

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've finished most things, but when I put a photo, its position is in ridiculous places. I created a new div inside main it has a photo class. But there is a problem with my positioning. Main stays at the top and a photo comes out from where the main ends at the bottom.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.photo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-top: 15pt;
  padding-left: 10pt;
  padding-right: 10pt;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="photo"><img src="assets/Artboard 9.png" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="header">
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div class="flex-container-item active"></div>
          <div class="flex-container-item active"></div>
...
...
...
```

Comment: Your [mcve] is incomplete and unverifiable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually stay under main. Since you give -1 to the z-index value in your class named Photo, it lags behind. If you set this value to 0, it will be ahead. That is, it is included in main under all conditions.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.photo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-top: 15pt;
  padding-left: 10pt;
  padding-right: 10pt;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="photo"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="header">
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div class="flex-container-item active"></div>
          <div class="flex-container-item active"></div>
```